# Is there a general construction for three-outcome qutrit POVMs?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, quantum-measurements

For qubits, I can consider the General POVM elements: $M_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(I \pm \hat{n}\cdot\overline{\sigma})$ where $\sigma $ is a vector containing the Pauli matrices and $\hat{n}$ a vector with norm less than one. This geometrically corresponds to antipodal points in the Bloch sphere.

My question is: is there an analogous construction for qutrits? This is, is there a similar way to construct 3 operators $M_0$, $M_1$, $M_2$ which represent the most general
POVM possible? I was thinking of the Gell-Mann matrices, but I do not know how to consider the analogous "antipodal property".

Comment: This is not the most general POVM possible for qubits. Also, what property do you want to generalize?

Comment: You may find a more receptive audience here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It is no the most general POVM because it is not the most general linear combination of the identity, and Pauli matrices, right? What I want is to violate (as much as I can) a Bell-like inequality using Qtrits. Then I need a way of expressing in some general form a POVM for three outcomes. I know usch problem can be solved with SDP, but this is not of my interest at the moment.

Comment: @hft Thanks a lot.

Comment: E.g. a general POVM could have an arbitrary number of outcomes.

Comment: aside from that not being a general single-qubit POVM, as a single-qubit POVM can have more than two outcomes (see eg SIC-POVM for a standard counterexample), it's also not the general form for a two-outcome POVM. As a trivial counterexample consider $M_1=3I/4$, $M_2=I/4$. Or $M_1=3I/4+X/4$, $M_2=I/4-X/4$, etc